# How to execute the parameterized stored procedure in SQLExecDirect

Tags: sql, sqlapi++

I want to execute a stored procedure using `SQLExecDirect()`.

So I am setting the input parameter using `SQLBindParameter()`. Also I am using `SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT` to bind the output parameter.

But after executing the query, I am getting `SQL_ERROR`. Here is the code.

```
SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, 
                                         SQL_CHAR , 40, 0, name, sizeof(name) ,
                                         SQL_NULL_HANDLE);

SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, 
                                         SQL_CHAR , 40, 0, userSID, sizeof(userSID) ,
                                         SQL_NULL_HANDLE);

r = SQLExecDirect(hStmt, "{ call Stored_procedure(?,?)}", SQL_NTS) ;
```

`Stored_procedure` will take 1 input parameter and also returns 1 output parameter it also return output.

I am able to execute this stored procedure. But I'm unable to get the value of the output parameters in the stored procedure.

Comment: Secondary question : If a question falls in a forest of unacceptance, and no-one is there to hear, does it make a sound?

Comment: @jadarnel27 Which would be a valid point *only* if the user hadn't had it explained previously.

Comment: @jadarnel27 so why don't you answer the question then?

Comment: @podiluska I'm not familiar with `SQLExecDirect()` at all.  I'm mainly active in asp.net / C# tags.  I just saw your comment from the review queue.